# How to create new instance of user control when I drag A-Panel or B-Panel to C-Panel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, drag-and-drop

Enviriontment : Visual studio C#/VB

Almost Information in internet, tell about Copy or Move object.
But I just make trigger for detecting drag a panel to other panel.

I have two panel (A_panel is red and B_panel is blue).They can drag then drop to C panel(C panel is green).
When I drop on C panel, A statement in "pnlC_DragDrop" must get name of A or B panel. A name will be parameter of creating new instance object. And get position of dropping for set position of new instant created.
[image]

```
     Private Sub ctrlBar_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load   
            pnlA.AllowDrop = True
            pnlB.AllowDrop = True 
            pnlC.AllowDrop = True               
     End Sub
```

...

```
      Private Sub pnlC_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles pnlC.DragEnter
           ' //Check Object must be panelA or panelB only. I have not do but it's not problem.
      End Sub
```

..

```
      Private Sub pnlC_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles pnlC.DragDrop
          If e.name = "panelA" Then
              Dim userCtrl As New UserControl("A")                  
          If e.name = "panelB" Then
              Dim userCtrl As New UserControl("B")
          End If
            userCtrl.location = new point(e.location.X,e.location.Y)
       End Sub
```

But Event"pnlC_dragDrop" is not work. I try to add breaking debug but it's not accessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like below...

```
Public Class ctrlBar

    Private Sub ctrlBar_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pnlA.AllowDrop = True
        pnlB.AllowDrop = True
        pnlC.AllowDrop = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub panelsAB_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pnlA.MouseMove, pnlB.MouseMove
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim pnl As Panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)
            Dim data As New DataObject(pnl.Name, pnl)
            pnl.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub pnlC_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles pnlC.DragEnter
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent("pnlA") Or e.Data.GetDataPresent("pnlB") Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub pnlC_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles pnlC.DragDrop
        Dim userCtrl As UserControl
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent("pnlA") Then
            userCtrl = New UserControl("A")
        Else
            userCtrl = New UserControl("B")
        End If
        userCtrl.Location = pnlC.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        pnlC.Controls.Add(userCtrl)
    End Sub

End Class
```